# Spark 2.0 streaming application load new keytab file for every renewal process

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, kerberos

we are using spark 2.0 for spark streaming application. we are moving our application to kerberos env. To do kerberos authentication, right now we are supplying keytab file, where spark automatically authenticates and renewes token where and whenever required.

```
--conf spark.yarn.keytab=user.keytab --conf spark.yarn.principal=user@######.COM --files user.keytab
```

we are told kerberos user password will be changed every week and new keytab file with same name will be placed in same location. so for the next time spark streaming application needs to renew token based on new keytab file not old one.

This is challenging for streaming application where it is continously running and keytab file is loaded into memory. Please let me know how we can load keytab file into spark memory for next renewal process.

Comment: To my best knowledge you need to manually write custom code to do this - besides restarting your streaming app once per period.

Comment: IMHO, with that kind of bizarre security requirement you can't avoid planned downtime. Worse, at some point the "promise" of seamless update of the keytabs at the right time will fail, and your app will crash and burn unexpectedly. To be on the safe side, just accept that you _must_ have downtime in your SLA (both planned and unplanned) and build your app to be resilient.